# How to audio out to iPad Pro when connected to HDMI?

Tags: ipad, hdmi, display

I have 3rd generation iPad pro. I use USB-C to HDMI adapter to connect my iPad to an external monitor with speaker.

The speaker on the monitor is so bad..I would love to use iPad speaker instead.

I've looked up everywhere, but it looks like there is no way to disable audio out to HDMI.

Is there a way to turn off HDMI audio out?

Comment: You can't use the builtin speaker, but you can use any wireless speakers/headphones connected to the iPad.  Very frustrating.  Classic Apple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately not. As far as iOS is concerned, HDMI works at the device level, and responds according to the EDID of the display device - if the display announces via its EDID it handles audio as well, then the iPad will switch audio over to the display device, in accordance with HDCP and the HDMI spec.

Comment: It seems to be the same with DisplayPort. I’m using a USB C to DisplayPort cable. It’s pretty bad because I can’t even hear audio on my Bluetooth headphones, so no workaround. On an iPad Air 4 from 2020.

Answer (score 5):

I’m using an iPad Pro 12.9” 3rd gen. I’ve found that I have the same behavior. I was able to manually switch the audio by going to control center, tap the audio sharing button and then select the built-in speakers or other connected device. I use my wireless headphones. It doesn’t always stick, but I’ve found once you set it, it tends to stay put.

Comment: You can not select iPad's built-in speaker. There is no such option. Maybe it is possible in future, but not at the moment June, 2020.

Comment: I was looking for this thank you. It worked. What he refers is the “publish” sign in the “now playing” box on control center.

Comment: Yes worked for me. If you have an external Bluetooth speaker

Comment: Holly shit this actually worked!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know this is old but I found a solution that worked for me.
I have my ipad pro m1 connected to a caldigit ts3 dock with a 4k monitor and built in speakers. There is also external speakers connected to the dock via usb. However the ipad would not let me choose my output. The sound is coming off the 4k display not the externals speakers. What I did was: clicking through the display settings and muting the display speakers. Then I reconnected the thunderbolt cable and voilá the ipad now selected the external usb speakers. Hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

Good answer here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251696756?sortBy=best.

*With the iPad connected to the external screen, scroll down your IPad screen to access the Control Centre, and in the music/sound box, press the Airplay button. You should then see an option to switch to your speakers/headphones.*